# Dependence of distance function on Riemannian metric

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a closed Riemannian manifold. Suppose that we have two metrics $g_1$ and $g_2$ which are $C^k$-close for some $k$. These two metrics have associated distance functions
$d_1$ and $d_2$ on $M \times M$. These are continuous functions which are smooth on the locus $N_\epsilon(\Delta) \setminus \Delta$ where $\Delta$ is the diagonal in $M \times M$ and $N_\epsilon(\Delta)$ is some small open $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the diagonal.

What can we say about the relationship between the distance functions given the knowledge that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are $C^k$-close? Are the distance functions $C^k$-close or do we get something worse, like $C^{k-1}$-close?

Comment: I guess you want to square those distance functions - without that they are not smooth

Comment: Thanks. I wrote "smooth on $N_\epsilon(\Delta) \setminus \Delta$" above (i.e. smooth outside the diagonal) but there was a typo so it didn't render properly.

Comment: Can you indicate your approach and progress on the question?

Comment: Hi Ted, thanks for the reply. It is straightforward that the distance functions are $C^0$ close when the metrics are $C^0$ close by definition. This is because the length of a path $\gamma$ with respect to $g_1$ will differ from its path with respect to $g_2$ by $\leq \|g_1 - g_2\|_{C^0} \cdot \text{Length}(\gamma)$, where we measure the $C^0$ norm and the length of $\gamma$ with respect to some auxiliary background metric. Taking a minimum over all paths connecting two points $p$ and $q$ shows a bound of the form $|d_1(p,q) - d_2(p,q)| \leq \|g_1 - g_2\|_{C^0} \cdot \text{Diam}(M)$.

Comment: I am at a bit of a loss at how to understand higher derivatives via the variational definition of the distance, however.

Comment: As another note, the first variation of arc-length along a path with respect to a metric $g$ will not change by much when taking a $C^1$ perturbation. In this vein, it is also I suppose easy to show that the $k$th variation does not change by much when taking a $C^k$ perturbation. Unfortunately, the distance function is an infimum over path lengths, so it may stand to reason that we can't do any better than $C^0$ closeness...

Answer (score 1):

I will show that if the metrics are $C^1$ close then so are their respective distance functions. I guess the proof can be iterated and thus one should be able to show that if the metrics are $C^k$ close then also the distance functions are $C^k$ close.

As pointed out in a comment, if two metrics are $C^0$ close, then their distance functions are also $C^0$ close. Now, let $g$ be a metric with induced distance function $d$, and note that the gradient of $d$ with respect to $g$ is given by
$$
\nabla_g d(x,y) = (u_1,u_2) \in T_{(x,y)} (M \times M) \simeq T_xM \oplus T_yM ,
$$
where $u_1 = -\gamma'(0)$, $u_2 = \gamma'(d(x,y))$, and $\gamma: [0,d(x,y)] \to M$ is the *unique* unit speed geodesic joining $x$ to $y$. In other words, we have
$$
\nabla_g d(x,y) = (\nabla_g d^y(x),\nabla_g d^x(y)) ,
$$
where $d^z(\cdot)$, $z \in M$, is the "distance to $z$" function.

We argue by contradiction. Let the sequence of metrics $g_n \to g$ in $C^1$, and assume that the sequence of induced distance functions $d_n$ does not converge in $C^1$ to $d$. Since they do converge in $C^0$, this means there is a sequence $(x_n,y_n) \in M \times M$ and an $\epsilon > 0$ such that
$$
|\nabla_{g_n} d_n(x_n,y_n) - \nabla_g d(x_n,y_n)|_g \geq \epsilon . \tag{1}
$$
Without loss of generality assume $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y)$, $x \neq y$, and note that $d_n(x_n,x_n) \to d(x,y)$ by $C^0$ convergence. Let $\gamma_n$ be the unique unit speed geodesics in the metrics $g_n$ joining $x_n$ to $y_n$, and let $\gamma$ be the unique geodesic joining $x$ to $y$. Write $\gamma_n'(0) = u_n$, $\gamma'(0) = u$. A simple calculation shows
$$
||u_n|_g - 1| = O(\|g_n-g\|_{C^0})
$$
and thus we can assume without loss of generality that $(x_n,u_n)$ converges to some $(x,w)$ in $TM$, where $|w|_g = 1$. By the inequality in $(1)$ we can also suppose $w \neq u$. Consider the geodesic $\alpha$ (in $g$) given by
$$
\alpha(0) = y , \quad \alpha'(0) = w .
$$
Since $g_n \to g$ in $C^1$, by ODE theory we have that $\gamma_n \to \alpha$ in $C^1$. Also, since $\gamma$ is the unique geodesic joining $x$ and $y$, and by our hypothesis $w = \alpha'(0) \neq \gamma'(0) = u$, we have $\alpha(s) \neq y$ for all $s \in [0, d(x,y) + \delta)$ for some $\delta > 0$. All these imply that $y_n = \gamma_n(d_n(x_n,y_n)) \to \alpha(d(x,y)) \neq y$, which is the desired contradiction.